# could not open db , $ is not defined, Failed to load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexeddb

The error is that the db could not be opened and $ not defined, failed to load resources(j query).The code aims at receiving the input field values(date,cal) and storing them into the database using indexedDB

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.webapp" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Diab</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="diab.css">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="diab1.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" id="date">Date</input>
    <input type="number" id="cal">Cal</input>
    <button id="add" >Add</button>
</body>
</html>



(function()
{   var db;
    var openDb=function()
    {
        var request=indexedDB.open("diabetore");
        request.onsuccess = function()
        {
            console.log("DB created succcessfully");
            db = request.result;
            console.log("openDB done!!");
        };


        request.onerror=function(){
            alert("could not open db");
        };

        request.onupgradeneeded = function()
        { 


        console.log("openDB.onupgradeneeded function");
        var store = db.createObjectStore("diab", {keyPath:  "date"});
        var dateIndex = store.createIndex("date", "date",{unique: true});

            // Populate with initial data.
            store.put({date: "june 1 2013",cal:70});
            store.put({date: "june 2 2013",cal:71});
            store.put({date: "june 3 2013",cal:72});
            store.put({date: "june 8 2013",cal:73});
        };   
    };

    function getObjectStore(store_name,mode)
    {
        var tx=db.transaction(store_name,mode);
        return tx.objectStore(store_name);
    }

    function addItems(date,cal)
    {
        console.log("addition to db started");
        var obj={date:date,cal:cal};
        var store=getObjectStore("diab",'readwrite');
        var req;
        try
        {
            req=store.add(obj);
        }catch(e)
        {
            if(e.name=='DataCloneError')
            alert("This engine doesn't know how to clone");
            throw(e);
        }
        req.onsuccess=function(evt)
        {
            console.log("****Insertion in DB successful!!****");

        };
        req.onerror=function(evt)
        {
            console.log("Could not insert into DB");
        };

    }

    function addEventListners()
    {
        console.log("addEventListeners called...");
        $('#add').click(function(evt){
            console.log("add...");
            var date=$('#date').val();
            var cal=$('#cal').val();
            if(!date || !cal)
            {
                alert("required field missing..");
                return;
            }
            addItems(date,cal);
        });
    }

    openDb();
    addEventListners();


})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the problem of not being able to see the db created, when you open the database you should pass another parameter with the version of the database, like:

```
var request=indexedDB.open("diabetore",1);
```

To see the DB structure on the Resources tab of Chrome Developer Tools, sometimes you must refresh the page.

You will also have a problem with your addEventListners() function since your anonymous function is run before the browser reads the HTML content so the browser doesn't not know about the '#add' element, so the click event handler for that element is not created.

You should put your code inside "$(function() {" or "$(document).ready(function() {":

```
$(function() {
    (function() {
       var db;
       var openDb=function() {
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion....it solved much of the issue...but the new problem is that i get Not Found Error: IDBdatabase Exception8 in the function getObjectStore. Also the function onupgradeneeded never got called..so no store was created. please help

Comment: Have you checked on the Resources tab of Chrome Developer Tools if the database was created? The onupgradeneeded event is only called when the db does not exist or the version is different.

Comment: yeah i checked it, db was not created, then i changed the version and again run the code,it worked fine and all other subsequent operations went well. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You should test the script URL in your browser. Then you'd realize that the script doesn't exist.

You need to change 2.0 to 2.0.0 for example.

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks a lot...at least the script run...but this is just half of the problem.... i am still not able to add to the db ....plz look into the event listener too.....also suggest any way to look into the structure of the db.... i am currently using chrome developer tools...there in resources tab no db has been created...help.